# NSString drawinrect issue (related to View setNeedsDisplay)

Tags: ios, setneedsdisplay

my app draws a string on a view. I have another slider control, which works in this way: when I change the slider's value, the string on the view also changes. But every time the string is redrawn it seems to overlap the old string and make the strings unclear.

my string drawing method is like this:

```
- (void)drawString:(NSString *)s withFont:(UIFont *)font inRect:(CGRect)contextRect {

    CGFloat fontHeight = font.pointSize;
    CGFloat yOffset = (contextRect.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0;

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(contextRect.origin.x, contextRect.origin.y + yOffset, contextRect.size.width, fontHeight);
    [s drawInRect:textRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping
        alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

Then in drawRect method of the view, I override it to draw the string:

```
[self drawString:someDynamicStringChangedEachTimeTheSliderValueChanged withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0] inRect:textRect];
```

Then in view controller, on slider value changed event I put

```
- (void)sliderValueChangedBy:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {

        ..........
        [myView setNeedsDisplay];

    }
}
```

I found that after a few times of the value change the string goes blurry and overlap. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: This just draws a string.  Since you never erase the old one, it just keeps drawing string after string after string....  Unless you have a good reason for doing it this way, you should probably just use a `UILablel` for text that changes like this.

Comment: I thought setNeedsDisplay would redraw things in a view. How can I erase the old strings?

Comment: Not easily, which is why I suggested that you use a label.  That's what it was designed for.  You can "erase" your string by drawing an empty box over it that is the same color as your background.

Comment: +1 to @inafziger. Why aren't you using a label?

Comment: Thanks I've tried your advice and it works smoothly.

Comment: -1 to @inafziger. `clearsContextBeforeDrawing
` will achieve what is required. But you should still be using a label, if that's all the drawing you're doing.

Comment: Also, you can do it manually as Inafziger says but an easier way is to draw a transparent box.

Comment: @jrturton: Does that work with UIKit methods like this that use the current graphics context?